# Ng-model values don't show up with multiple Angular Bootstrap UI Datetime pickers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I used Datetime picker for a single input, it worked fine.

But when I used ng-repeat and the ng-model values didn't show up inside the input box though ng-model values were saved properly.

Please check the following code:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="error-input" 
      ng-if="vm.editForm['employeeOnProjectStartDate'+$index].$error.required && vm.isSavedBefore">
   This field is required
   </span>                                                                
   <input type="text" class="form-control" required 
      name="employeeOnProjectStartDate{{$index}}"  
      enable-time="false" datetime-picker="dd-MMM-yyyy" ng-model="employee.employeeOnProjectStartDate"
      is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.employeeOnProjectStartDate[$index]"  />
   <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('employeeOnProjectStartDate',$index)">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
   </button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to add ng-value as well. 
ng-value="employee.employeeOnProjectStartDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'" solved the issue.